# Google Apps Script - Data find copy and past into last empty cell of a column

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying for a few days to do some data manipulation but it seems that I could figure this out myself.
Basically, I have my row data that I have extracted and cleaned from my csv file in a dedicated sheet (data). There is 2 parameter that I am trying to use. The unique ID (Name) and the Position (5 differents value possible).

The idea is to go through the sheet (Data) en regroup all the name for a specific Position into a new Sheet (Sorted).

**Example of the data:**
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEezG.png)

**Expected result:**[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrCKC.png)

Here is the code I started to work on but it far from being efficient:

```js
function display(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');  
  var sorted = ss.getSheetByName('Sorted');
 
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var rangesorted = sorted.getDataRange();
  var rangeVals = range.getValues();
  var rangesortedVals = rangesorted.getValues();
  var name;
  var position;
  
  for (var i = 1; i <= rangeVals.length; i++) {
    position = rangeVals[i][2];
    name = rangeVals[i][1];
    for (var j = 1; j <= 5; j++){
     if (rangesortedVals[1][j] === position) {
       sorted.getRange(i,j).setValue(name);
      //missing the part where i look for the last empty cell to past the name
     }
    }
  } 

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function display() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//data sheet
  const osh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');//output sheet
  osh.clear();//clear output sheet
  const values=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();
  let np={pA:[]};
  values.forEach((v,i)=>{
    if(!np.hasOwnProperty(v[1])) {
      np[v[1]]=[];
      np[v[1]].push([v[0]]);
      np.pA.push(v[1]);
    } else {
      np[v[1]].push([v[0]]);
    }
  });
  let oA=np.pA.map((e,i)=>{return[[e],...np[e]];});//output column array
  oA.forEach((c,i)=>{osh.getRange(1,i+1,c.length,1).setValues(c);});//loading columns
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();//not absolutely required
}
```

My Data from Sheet1:

| Name | Position |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | one |
| Name2 | two |
| Name3 | three |
| Name4 | one |
| Name5 | two |
| Name6 | three |
| Name7 | one |
| Name8 | two |
| Name9 | three |
| Name10 | one |
| Name11 | two |
| Name12 | three |
| Name13 | one |
| Name14 | two |
| Name15 | three |
| Name16 | one |
| Name17 | two |
| Name18 | three |
| Name19 | Four |

My output Sheet2:

| one | two | three | Four |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Name19 |
| Name4 | Name5 | Name6 |  |
| Name7 | Name8 | Name9 |  |
| Name10 | Name11 | Name12 |  |
| Name13 | Name14 | Name15 |  |
| Name16 | Name17 | Name18 |  |

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

I will take the time to understand and do the necessary adaptation.

Comment: I think all you have to do is change sheet names.  I just chose values that are easy to copy quickly if you want to see it done with your data then just provide your data in a table.  Note: not a spreadsheet because I don't follow links to spreadsheets

Comment: Works marvellously. 
Thanks a Lot